# Pandas unique values in two columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am very new to pandas. I have two dataframes related to two player Game

```
DF1:matches # match information 

match_num   winner_id   loser_id    points
270      201504         201595       28
271      201514         201426       19
272      201697         211901       21             
273      201620         211539       30 
274      214981         203564.      10
```

for match num `270` both players `201504 -> winner`  and `201595-> loser` shared `28` points each.

I need to find out Which player(s) got the highest number of points overall?

I am using Hashmap to solve this problem?

```py
hmap = defaultdict(int)
for index,row in matches_df.iterrows():
    hmap[row["winner_id"]] +=  row["points"]
    hmap[row["loser_id"]] +=  row["points"]
max_key = max(hmap, key=hmap.get)
```

Is this can be solved using pandas SQL way?

Comment: Try: print(df[df['points'] == df['points'].max()])

Comment: kindly post the expected output dataframe

Comment: The output just the winner_id who has the maximum point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User `melt` to stack the two id columns, then groupby:

```
(df[['winner_id','loser_id','points']]
   .melt('points', value_name='id')
   .groupby('id')['points'].sum()
)
```

Output:

```
id
201426.0    19
201504.0    28
201514.0    19
201595.0    28
201620.0    30
201697.0    21
203564.0    10
211539.0    30
211901.0    21
214981.0    10
Name: points, dtype: int64
```

Comment: how to get the player with maximum point, using sorting if so what happens if we have multiple player with same points

Comment: Let `s` be the series above, then `s.idxmax()` to get one player. To get all players use `s[s.eq(s.max())].index` for all users with max score.